# Is it possible to close an SPL token Mint account?

Tags: spl-token, pda, mint

Currently, we have code that could end up generating a lot of `Mint`s in PDAs. We want users to be able to close these out as they're not neccessarily meant to stick around forever, but is that even possible? I don't see a method for it.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/3435 suggests that it's not, but I was wondering if there's something I'm missing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spl-token you cannot close Mint accounts.

In the already released token22, you have the ability to [close the mint accounts with the new instruction](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#example-closing-a-mint). This new standard has not gotten critical adoption at this time

Comment: What is the difference between closing a mint and disabling the mint? I was told about this: `spl-token authorize TOKEN_ID mint --disable` and that it causes places like Solana Explorer to describe the token as being in "Fixed Supply". What will token22's closing of the mint do differently?

Comment: This is always surprising me that the solana stack exchange do not provide link to documentation but just claim some thought. I would really appreciate more information about this than just "you cannot".

Comment: Docs often focus on what you can do instead of what you cannot. I gave a link to the future docs where you can @S.R

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as splToken from '@solana/spl-token'
```

you can close only the empty accounts. Write an instruction.

```
const intstuction= splToken.Token.createCloseAccountInstruction(
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    pubKeyOfAccount,
    owner,
    owner,
    // this is multisigner
    []
)
```

create transaction

```
 import {Connection,Transaction,sendAndConfirmTransaction} from '@solana/web3.js';

 const transaction=new Transaction.add(instruction)
```

then run `sendAndConfirmTransaction`.

```
const transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  signers
);
```